# What's the explanation for this behavior: ES6 Promise that is never resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

The following code:

```
Promise.resolve('a string')
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('resp from the initial promise: ' + resp)
    const p0 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('finished sleeping in p0')
        resolve('hello from p0')
      }, 5000)
    })
    console.log('returning p0')
    return p0
  })
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('resp from p0: ' + resp)
    const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('p1 completed')
      // resolve('another string from p1')
    })
    console.log('returning p1')
    return p1
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('resp from p1: ' + res)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error: ' + err.message)
  })

console.log('last statement')
```

When I run that, I get the following output (that doesn't make sense to me)

```
last statement
resp from the initial promise: a string
returning p0
finished sleeping in p0
resp from p0: hello from p0
p1 completed
returning p1
```

First of all, since the promise `p1` is never resolved, I'd expect the program to just wait forever and never finish. That is not the case and it finishes just fine (albeit without ever getting to the last `then()`).

Also, it creates the promise and executes the code inside of the promise *before* the code that comes after it's created. I would expect 'returning p1' to come *before* 'p1 completed' since I assumed that what's inside the promise would be executed on the next tick.

Comment: [Consider reviewing the Promise docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters).

Comment: p1 is never resolved.. self explanatory.

Comment: so, uh, think about where you are calling `console.log('p1 completed')`

Comment: @StevenStark I assumed that if p1 is never resolved the promise chain would just wait forever for it to resolve. Obviously that seems to not be the case, but I'd like more explanation as to why this is. It seems reasonable to me that making a promise implies that you want to wait until it finishes. If it never can finish, why would the program end?

Comment: Why does it seem like it's not the case? The chain doesn't continue.

Comment: It works as intended. As for the order of p1 logs, in most cases only setTimeout/setInterval would "move" the execution to the next tick. Furthermore, the "program" does not end as it never reaches the last `then`. It's forever stuck in the p1 promise as it's never resolved

Comment: @zzzzBov This is probably the best answer. I obviously had a big misunderstanding as to what's going on when a promise is executed. It took about 10 secs of reading that link to figure it out. :)

Comment: any promise you return in the chain replaces the original promise. Here, p1 is replacing the chain and does not have code that resolves, producing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, it creates the promise and executes the code inside of the promise before the code that comes after it's created. I would expect 'returning p1' to come before 'p1 completed' since I assumed that what's inside the promise would be executed on the next tick.

If you call `.then` on a promise, the function that you pass in will be delayed until the next tick. But the constructor of a promise does not behave that way. When you construct a `new Promise`, the code that you pass into the constructor is run immediately and synchronously. So this code:

```
const p0 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('finished sleeping in p0')
    resolve('hello from p0')
  }, 5000)
})
console.log('returning p0')
```

... will immediately set a timeout, before the promise even gets assigned to `p0`. And this code:

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('p1 completed')
  // resolve('another string from p1')
})
console.log('returning p1')
```

... will immediately log out 'p1 completed', before the promise even gets assigned to `p1`.

Comment: I'd also mention that since `resolve` and `reject` for `p1` have fallen out of scope, `p1` can be garbage collected as soon as it's returned from the `.then()` callback, allowing the event loop to terminate since there are no more scheduled ticks.

Comment: Although I just did a quick test. Interestingly enough, even if `resolve` hasn't fallen out of scope yet, if the `setTimeout()` is `unref()`'d, the program will still terminate early. I guess that means pending promises that still have the potential to resolve are not strongly referenced by the event loop... that seems like a problem to me.